# How to pass a UIscrollview to be used by delegate class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am not new to delegates but I AM new to the syntax to create a delegate in its own class.

Essentially I have a PickerView delegate that I have created in its own class.  I want to be able to put the selection text into a textbox in a UIScrollView that has been declared in my ViewController.  However I don't know the syntax to show the delegate the view.  Here are the .h and .m files of the delegate.  If there are any other missing components I need to have my ViewController see my delegate that I do not have, please let me know as well.  The error is in the didSelectRow method.

RadioPickerDelegate.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 @class MissionInputViewController;


 @interface RadioPickerDelegate : NSObject<UITextFieldDelegate>{
   NSArray *radioOptions;
 }
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *radioOptions;


 @end
```

RadioPickerDelegate.M

```
#import "RadioPickerDelegate.h"
#import "MissionInputViewController.h"

@implementation RadioPickerDelegate

@synthesize radioOptions;

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Handle the selection
    UITextField *textField =  (UITextField *)[inputsView viewWithTag:pickerView.tag];
    textField.text = [radioOptions objectAtIndex:row];


     //The error is at the inputsView value.  That is my UIScrollView from the view controller

}

// tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return 2;    

}

// tell the picker how many components it will have
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

// tell the picker the title for a given component
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    radioOptions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Yes", @"No"];

   return [radioOptions objectAtIndex:row];


}

// tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int sectionWidth = 200;

    return sectionWidth;
}



@end
```

Basically I want to create a PickerView in my ViewController and have it use this delegate.  Then this delegate must update a textfield in a UIScrollView in my ViewController.  I need to somehow have this delegate see/use that UIScrollView(inputsView).

Thanks

Comment: where you have defined `inputsView`???

Comment: I haven't.  Which is obviously the issue.  I don't know how.  If I just create a UIScrollView varible with the name inputsView.. that won't be the same view that I want to use.

Comment: where is you `UIScrollView` defined and where have you created the object of the `RadioPickerDelegate` class

Comment: UIScrollView is defined in my view controller.  I would create the object of the RadioPickerDelegate there as well to be used.  I just haven't yet because I haven't gotten past this issue.  I'm not even 100% sure this delegate is syntactically correct or set up at all correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited again

your view controller class

here you are passing the reference of your text field (say textFiledSV) to the radio picker class

```
//set the delegate where you have created the object of RadioPickerDelegate class
radioPickerDelegateObject.textField = yourTextField;
```

RadioPickerDelegate.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class MissionInputViewController;


@interface RadioPickerDelegate : NSObject<UIPickerViewDelegate>{
    NSArray *radioOptions;
    //Text Field so that we can set it's value
    UITextField *textField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *radioOptions;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITextField *textField;

@end
```

RadioPickerDelegate.m file

```
#import "RadioPickerDelegate.h"
#import "MissionInputViewController.h"

@implementation RadioPickerDelegate

@synthesize radioOptions;
@synthesize textField;

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
   //here you are setting the text of the text field which was passed priviously (textFiledSV) thus it changes the text of the textField of you UIScrollView
   textField.text = [radioOptions objectAtIndex:row];  
}

//other method definitions

@end
```

Comment: I think I am a little confused..  My understanding is I need to create a UIPickerView with a class to handle its delegate methods.  That class is suppose to be RadioPickerDelegate.  What does setting my radioPickerDelegateObject's delegate to its self do?   Is that strictly for the passing of the string?

Comment: yes you are confused... you don't need to create a separate class to handle UIPickerView delegate.. you can set its delegate to MissionInputViewController class and handle all its delegate methods there

Comment: Yes, I know.  NORMALLY you would be able to.  However I have about 3 different types of UIPickerViews that need to be on the same screen.  Each type must be handled differently and each type can have multiples.  So I figured separate delegates for each of the three types would be best.

Comment: This still doesn't look like it solves the problem.  This sets the value of the textfield in my UIScrollView(which should be blank) to into the value of the textfield variable in my delegate.  It should be the other way around.  The delegate method didSelectRow should set the value of the textfield in the UIScrollView.

Comment: my dear it is setting the value of text field's text in the UIScrollView from didSelectRow.. see the above code again and carefully

Comment: I guess I am missing something then.  When the user selects a row textField.text is set to that value.  Then, somewhere in the controller class.  With the line 'radioPickerDelegateObject.textField = yourTextField'  You are taking the value inside 'yourtextfield' (which would be blank) and setting it to 'radioPickerDelegateObject's textField' variable.  Overwriting whatever the user chose.  I fail to see where at any point, the value in textField.text(the value the user selected) is put into yourTextField.text(the text field I want to populate with the users selection)

Comment: step by step now..  1. Set the `radioPickerDelegateObject.textField = yourTextField` 
2. now user select the row. 
3. in didSelectRow you set `textField.text = [radioOptions objectAtIndex:row];` 
now this text field is that one which you passes from the controller..

Comment: Oooooh OK I see what is happening now.  You are passing the reference to the text field itself, rather than the value IN the text field.  I guess my next question would be.. how does this work for more than 1 pickerview and more than one text field using the same delegate?  All created dynamically....

Comment: I have no way of knowing how many text fields or picker views will be made prior to runtime.  If I repeatedly pass the textfield to the delegate... does objective c create new instances each time? or will it just overwrite the instance over and over.

Comment: you are just passing the reference not creating this one as `@property (nonatomic, assign) UITextField *textField;` it is `assign` not `copy` so no extra object is created. it will override again and again

Comment: Ok.  This definitely works and is on the right track.  But won't quite solve all my issues.  I'll have to think about this a bit more.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I thought of a possible solution.. Since you can pass the instance of the text field in this manner.. could it be possible to just pass the entire UIScrollView?  So when the delegate edits the 'inputsView' variable, it edits the view itself?

Comment: Well so far no syntax errors. But it doesn't seem to actually be using the delegate.  My pickers are just blank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the error is from `inputsView` which isn't declared anywhere.

And your interface is saying it conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate` instead of `< UIPickerViewDelegate>`

Comment: The two class files I posted are SUPPOSE to be a PickerView delegate.  Would I need the interface to implement it like that?

Comment: Yes, by adding the <UIPickerViewDelegate> you are telling users of the class that it conforms to that protocol, and can be treated as that type. But that isn't going to fix your error from inputsView not being defined anywhere in the class.

Comment: I understand.  As I said in the OP, I'm not so sure my RadioPickerDelegate class files are setup correctly in the first place.

Comment: Well then this question is nothing to do with delegates, but foundation Objective-C (or most language's) - you can't reference a variable, `inputsView`, in a file unless it has been declared somewhere first.

Comment: It has been declared.  inputsView has been declared in my ViewController.  I need to somehow have my delegate class see/use that variable so I can update a textfield.

Comment: If I just create a new UIScrollView named inputsView in my delegate, that won't update the view I need will it?